# Error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Button

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I have a problem with this code:

```
{
    TextView txt;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

        btn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V){
                txt.setText("TAK");
            }
        });
}
```

As result, I get error that says:

> incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Button

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Basicly what happen is that the view `mybutton` is not a `Button` type.

Comment: Could you add the relevant layout code and specify which line exactly is throwing the error? It seems that you are trying to cast some other `View` into a `Button`, which leads to this error.

Comment: I recommend you to look at the xml file and check what type the view `mybutton` is.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) indicate which code line the compiler is referring to (by line # or using a `// code comment`

Answer (score 1):

Check your activity's xml file , mybutton should be another view component.

Your xml view button should be like this:

```
<Button
   android:text="Button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/mybutton" />
```

check if is not an ImageButton or  ToggleButton.

Comment: That's not the issue. If the issue was in the xml, it would lead to a compiler error, not to an error during execution.

Comment: @WholeBrain *"..not to an error during execution"* The reported problem **is a** compile time error. A run-time error would be more along the lines of a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: My bad ! Thanks.